# firebase expired idToken becoming invalid after 1 week

Tags: python, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm using Firebase auth with python.

When the user login I get `idToken` and `refreshToken`. After 1hr the `idToken` will be expired. 
At this moment we can check that the token is expired `auth.verify_id_token(idToken)` by getting `ExpiredIdTokenError` exception.

After 1 week (approximately) if we want to check the token we will have InvalidIdTokenError: `Certificate for key id f55e294eedc167cd97bb5a819bbf790636f1237e not found.`

It happens because the `idToken` `kid`(key_id) is different than in the cert  `https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com`
But I don't believe that the Google Certificate is being changed each week.

dependencies: 
firebase-admin==5.0.3 
oauth2client==4.1.3
python3

the firebase_admin code

```
    # fetch certs from 'https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com'
    certs = _fetch_certs(request, certs_url)
.....
        if key_id:
            if key_id not in certs:
                raise ValueError("Certificate for key id {} not found.".format(key_id))
```

Comment: Google public keys do indeed change at least once a week (sometimes more often).

Comment: how to prevent it?

Comment: You can't. Key rotation is a critical security measure built into the service. In any case, the SDK catches these errors and converts them into `InvalidIdTokenError`. So you can just handle that to deal with this scenario.